# How to Access Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded and installed Ubuntu from CD, but it doesn't show up when I reboot. How do I switch from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: We need more information.  Is this is a laptop or desktop?  What version of Windows?  Did it come pre-installed?  Is it UEFI or BIOS?  What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: and did you remove the CD after installing?

Comment: Its a desktop, with Windows Office XP Pro. I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 off a CD. Upon completion of the installation, when it said I needed to restart, I clicked on restart, but it never acted. I powered off the computer and restarted, and removed the CD as the computer was restarting. I don't know if it is UEFI or BIOS, BIOS is what I see as the computer is starting.

Answer (score 0):

Try boot-repair by booting into Ubuntu from live CD.

Install boot repair --> For this, open a terminal and do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Run boot-repair -->

```
sudo boot-repair
```

Click on `Recommended repair`. Write on a paper the new URL that will appear.

Reboot your PC

Comment: Can you be more specific. What do you mean, open a terminal? I tried "run", it said sudo not recognized.

Comment: Press (Ctrl + Alt + T) to open a terminal and then follow the steps as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Nothing happens.